# Too few arguments to function Slim\Views\TwigExtension::__construct(), 0 passed and exactly 2 expected

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to generate a link to a delete method using the `urlFor` helper, and i am using twig extensions to utilize the urlFor method but im getting the error

`Too few arguments to function Slim\Views\TwigExtension::__construct(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eli35/src/dependencies.php on line 47 and exactly 2 expected`

not sure what to include in the parameters.

Ultimately im trying to click on the delete link to delete a task.

Any suggestions, thanks in advance.

Here is the **dependencies.php** file.

```
<?php
// DIC configuration




$container = $app->getContainer();


// view renderer
$container['renderer'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['renderer'];
    return new Slim\Views\PhpRenderer($settings['template_path']);
};

// monolog
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']));
    return $logger;
};


$container['db'] = function($c){
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['db'];
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $settings['host'] . ";dbname=" . $settings['dbname'] . ";port=" . $settings['port'],
    $settings['user'], $settings['pass']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
};



$container['view'] = function ($container) {
    $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig( 'views', [
        'cache' => false,
    ]);
    $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
        $container->router,
        $container->request->getUri()
    ));

    $view->parserExtensions = array(
        new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(),
    );

    return $view;
};
```

here is the section of the **TodosController.php** for my delete method

```
public function deleteTodo($request, $response, $args)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE id=:id");
    $sth->bindParam("id", $args['id']);
    $sth->execute();
    $todos = $sth->fetchAll();


    return $this->response->withRedirect('/todos');


}
```

here is the route link for my delete method, its in the routes file

`$app->delete('/todo/[{id}]', '\App\Controllers\TodosController:deleteTodo')->setName("deletetask");`

here is **todos.twig** where im displaying the delete link

```
{% extends "templates/layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>My Todos</h1>

<ol>
  {% for task in todos %}
        <div class="myl">
        <li><h4>{{ task.task}}</h4></li>
        <small style="font-style:italic">{{task.created_at |date("m/d/Y")}}</small></br>


        <a href="{{ urlFor('deletetask', {'id': task.id}) }}">Delete</a>



        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</ol>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Did you read the error? It clearly says that on line 47 your call `new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension()` should contain 2 parameters and you gave 0. Use it like everywhere else, with 2 parameters.

Comment: @sidyll what should i put in the parameters ?

Comment: Probably router and uri, just like the rest of the code... wasn't it written by you?

Comment: I used the slim skeleton and i adjusted it to my liking. 

can you elaborate more about what to include in the parameters, im a bit new to using slim

Comment: i added  `$container->router,
            $container->request->getUri()` and now i get  `: Unknown "urlFor" function.`

Comment: Try this: `$view->parseExtensions = array( 
 new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension
);`

Comment: I'm just reading the errors. `urlFor()` was an app method but it was replaced by `pathFor()`, a router method.

Comment: @ultrasamad i got `Class 'TwigExtension' not found`

Comment: @ultrasamad i had to do ` new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension` but still got the same error in the original post

Comment: @Owl Man with the full name spacing in place? You shouldn't get that error, check the edited comment.

Comment: @ultrasamad i did, here is the error ` Too few arguments to function Slim\Views\TwigExtension::__construct(), 0 passed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eli35/src/dependencies.php on line 46 and exactly 2 expected`

Comment: Then pass in those two variables as you initially did to the constructor  and in your view file change `urlFor` to `pathFor`.

Comment: @ultrasamad i have a better question, forget about the twig extensions. how can i delete the task by clicking on the link.

this is what i have so far

`<a href="/todo/{{task.id}}">Delete</a>` it takes me to a json object i just want to delete it and redirect back home

Comment: @ultrasamad its not deleting its ignoring my app request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra junk code.

```
$container['view'] = function ($container) {
        $view = new \Slim\Views\Twig( 'views', [
            'cache' => false,
        ]);
        $view->addExtension(new \Slim\Views\TwigExtension(
            $container->router,
            '/'
        ));

        return $view;
    };
```